# Nuget configuration

Tags: c#, configuration, nuget

I've already **configured** it in the **nuget package** manager, but it doesn't work, and when I build a new project, I'll download DLL from the old configuration. As shown in the following figure.

The package **ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.5.14** cannot be found on source

> https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

*This address is already configured*

> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: This is the address of the configuration  “https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json ”

Comment: What version of Dev Studio are you using?

Comment: vs2017 and vs 2015